# Fluid simulation with a visible image inside the liquid

Tags: rendering, materials, fluid-simulation

I would like to be able to see an 'image on a plane' inside a liquid with viscosity in (fluid simulation).

I have seen a few tutorial without much chance.
Screen space and reflexion is turned on in the material and in rendering.

Do you know all the parameters needed to do that?

I am using eevee

We should be able to see her feet.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach screenshots of your result and materials? And which render engine are you using?

Comment: I am using eevee. I just put a picture (modified) for you to see. Thank you.

Comment: It works now... Refraction depth was too much on... thanks anyway..

Comment: Glass refraction would look much better in Cycles